# Burning "pulver" on Simchas Torah?

Tags: melacha-creative-work, translation, yiddish, simchat-torah

The Chayei Adam writes that he's seen people burn "pulver" ["poolver"?] on Simchas Torah, and such a practice is totally halachically wrong and should be stopped. They may, however, leave a tube of *pulver* next to a candle so it will ignite automatically.

What is this pulver, and why are people burning it? (Does he mean something like ... gunpowder, to make a big, "fun", bang sound?)

Comment: Where did you see this in Chayei Adam? It sounds like short for "pulverized"?

Comment: Polvere in Italian is powder. Perhaps a kind of gunpowder.

Comment: Shalom it would be really helpful if you include where he wrote this. It's actually even surprising that you didn't think to do so already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://glosbe.com/en/yi/gunpowder) that פּולווער is gunpowder and [here](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2008/10/simchat-torah.html) and [here](http://kehillatisrael.net/chagim/sukkot/simchat_torah.html) that it was common in some communities to light firecrackers on Simchat Torah.